# No defaultview of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to filter data that's loaded in the datagrid. This datagrid is bounded to an entity of EF. I read different posts on the internet about filtering and from all those posts I could create the code below. The problem is that I still can't get what I want to. An exception is thrown because "MyData" is NULL. Why doesn't defaultview return data?

This is the XAML

```
<Grid Name="gG" DataContext="{StaticResource t_KlantenViewSource}">
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="t_KlantenDataGrid" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" MouseDoubleClick="t_KlantenDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" Margin="0,21,0,10" FontSize="13">

    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Name="tbSearch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="0,-7,99.2,0" TextChanged="tbSearch_TextChanged" />
</Grid>
```

This is the code

```
CollectionViewSource t_KlantenViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("t_KlantenViewSource")));
        System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<AOV.t_Klanten> customersQuery = this.Getlt_KlantenQuery(aovent);
        t_KlantenViewSource.Source = customersQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);

private System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView MyData;
string SearchText = string.Empty;

    private void tbSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyData = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(t_KlantenDataGrid.DataContext);
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        SearchText = t.Text.ToString();
        MyData.Filter = FilterData;
    }
```

Comment: So what is happening, that you're not happy with the current state? No wonder, that no one wanted to help. We simply can't.

Comment: I get the following exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at MyData.Filter = FilterData; I checked and saw that MyData is NULL. No wonder that the exception is thrown. I cant't understand why MyData is NULL.

Comment: Just a quick shot, `t_KlantenDataGrid.DataContext` is `null`, when the first line of `tbSearch_TextChanged(...)` is executed.

Comment: No, the t_KlantenDataGrid.DataContext is not NULL.

Comment: Next quick shot, `t_KlantenDataGrid.DataContext` is of a type, which is not supported by `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(...)`.

Comment: So, what's next? What can I still do to be able to search data which is in the datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the first line as mentioned in below updated code. As GetDefaultView accepts the binding source.

```
 private void tbSearch_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyData = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(t_KlantenDataGrid.ItemsSource);
            TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
            SearchText = t.Text.ToString();
            MyData.Filter = FilterData;
        }
```